# Using logic to compare absolute values

Tags: python

Is there a way to make my code simpler/more Pythonic?

> Given three `int` values (`a, b, c`), return True if one of `b` or `c` is "close"
>   (differing from `a` by at most `1`), while the other is "far", differing
>   from both other values by `2` or more. Note: `abs(num)` computes the
>   absolute value of a number.
>
> `close_far(1, 2, 10)` → True
>   `close_far(1, 2, 3)` → False
>   `close_far(4, 1, 3)` → True

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
    if abs(a - b) <= 1 or abs(a - c) <= 1:
        if abs(c - a) >= 2 <= abs(c - b) or abs(b - a) >= 2 <= abs(b - c):
            return True       
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

- You could replace the innermost `if` with `return`
- Adding doctests would be nice
- Note that `abs(a - b)` is the same as `abs(b - a)`. To avoid repeated calculation of `abs` values, it would be more optimal to cache in local variables

Like this:

```
def close_far(a, b, c):
    """
    >>> close_far(1, 2, 10)
    True
    >>> close_far(1, 2, 3)
    False
    >>> close_far(4, 1, 3)
    True
    """
    diff_ab = abs(a - b)
    diff_ac = abs(a - c)
    if diff_ab <= 1 or diff_ac <= 1:
        diff_bc = abs(c - b)
        return diff_ac >= 2 <= diff_bc or diff_ab >= 2 <= diff_bc
    return False
```

Comment: excellent tips, I learned a lot, replacing the innermost if with return is only valid because that particular if returned true or false isn't it? (in other words there was boolean comparison inside of it)

Comment: Replacing with `return` is valid because if the rest of the function: if the condition is not true, the function will `return False` anyway, so the outcome is exactly the same, but shorter to write. Technically, you could flatten the entire `if`, but that it would be overall less readable: `return (abs(a - b) <= 1 or abs(a - c) <= 1) and abs(c - a) >= 2 <= abs(c - b) or abs(b - a) >= 2 <= abs(b - c)`